# Resolving array types in a Unity (Prism) container

Tags: arrays, unity-container, prism

Is it possible to register and resolve array types in a Unity container? I'd like to do something like this:

```
this.mContainer
    .RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeType>()
    .RegisterType<ISomeType[], SomeType[]>();
ISomeType[] lSomeTypes = this.mContainer.Resolve<ISomeType[6]>();
```

It would be even better if I didn't have to register the array type, and have Unity figure out the array based on `RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeType>()` and `Resolve<ISomeType[]>()` alone.

Comment: Found some documentation, but it wasn't very clear... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#_Toc260122621

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you register multiple types for a particular type (using named registrations), then when the container sees a dependency on an array of that type, it'll automatically inject all the named registrations.

So this will work:

```
this.mContainer
  .RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeImpl1>("one")
  .RegisterType<ISomeType, SomeOtherImpl>("other")
  .RegisterType,ISomeType, AnotherImpl>("another");

ISomeType[] someTypes = mContainer.Resolve<ISomeType[]>();
```

This logic will kick in whenever there's a dependency of ISomeType[] - constructor parameter, injected property, etc.

Note that the array injection will only inject *named* registrations. The default, unnamed registration is not included in the array.